# Php include header not showing on some machines

Tags: php, html

So i have an header and footer in seperate files, i include them via the php include method. On my machine it works on chrome and edge. When i go to a other pc it works on chrome but not on edge. Now when it doesn't load it actually loads but dissapears directly after. It is only on screen for a short flash.

My file structure is as following:

```
2.10.0
  index.php
  assets
     headernav.php
```

In my index.php file i use this code to include.

```
<?php include("assets/headernav.php"); ?>
```

The headernav.php file it includes is as follows

```
<script>
        function openmen() {
            document.getElementById("menu").style.marginLeft = "0";
            document.getElementById('menubtn').setAttribute("onClick", "closemen()");
      document.getElementById("content").style.paddingLeft = "250px";
      document.getElementById("searchbox").style.left = "240px";
        }

        function closemen() {
            document.getElementById("menu").style.marginLeft = "-230px";
            document.getElementById('menubtn').setAttribute("onClick", "openmen()");
      document.getElementById("content").style.paddingLeft = "20px";
      document.getElementById("searchbox").style.left = "10px";
    }
    function opensettings() {
            document.getElementById("settings").style.display = "block";
    }
    function closesettings() {
            document.getElementById("settings").style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
<settings_background id="settings">
<settings>
<h2>Instellingen</h2><i id="closebtn" onclick="closesettings()"  class="fas fa-times"></i>
<a>Eenheid</a>
<form method="POST" action="includes/units.inc.php">
    <input placeholder="Naam" class="inputmaterial" type="text" name="naam" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['naam']; ?>">
    <input placeholder="Callsign" class="inputmaterial" type="text" name="callsign" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['callsign']; ?>">
    <select Placeholder="department" class="inputmaterial" name="department">
          <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['department']; ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['department']; ?></option>
          <option value="Police">Police</option>
          <option value="Traffic police">Traffic police</option>
          <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
          <option value="Ems">Ems</option>
          <option value="Milatary police">Milatary police</option>
          <option value="Siu">Siu</option>
        </select>
    <input placeholder="rang/functie" class="inputmaterial" type="text" name="rang" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rang']; ?>">
    <input placeholder="Naam" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="index.php">
    <br><br><br><input style="float:left;"class="button_grey" type="submit" name="cookie" value="Save">
      </form>

  <a>Account</a>
   <form method="POST" action="login_v3/account.inc.php">
    <input placeholder="Huidig wachtwoord" class="inputmaterial" type="password" name="pwdold">
    <input placeholder="Nieuw wachtwoord" class="inputmaterial" type="password" name="password">
    <input placeholder="uid" type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
    <br><br><br><input class="button_grey" type="submit" name="updatepassword" value="Save">
  </form>

  <a>Personalisatie</a>
  <form action="includes/units.inc.php" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" id="id-name--1" name="meldingen" class="switch-input" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['notificaties'])){echo "checked";} ?>>
  <label for="id-name--1" class="switch-label">Meldingen <span class="toggle--on">Aan</span><span class="toggle--off">Uit</span></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="id-name--2" name="darkmode" class="switch-input" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['darkmode'])){echo "checked";} ?>>
  <label for="id-name--2" class="switch-label">Darkmode <span class="toggle--on">Aan</span><span class="toggle--off">Uit</span></label><br><br><br>*darkmode is nog in beta
  <input placeholder="Naam" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>">
  <br><br><input type="submit" name="personalisatie" value="Save" class="button_grey">
  </form>


</settings>
</settings_background>

<nav_menu id="menu"><div class="section">
  <a href="noodhulp.php"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Meldingen</a>
  <a href="search.php"><i class="fas fa-id-card"></i> Database</a>
  <a href="bolos.php"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Gezocht</a>
  <a href="map.php"><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> Kaarten</a>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
  <p>Verslagen</p>
  <a href='reports.php'><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i> Verslagen</a>
  <a><i class="fas fa-notes-medical"></i> Nieuw verslag</a>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
  <p>Registratie</p>
  <a href="reg.melding.php"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Maak melding</a>
  <a href="reg.offence.php?delict=overtreding"><i class="fas fa-receipt"></i> Bekeuring</a>
  <a href="reg.offence.php?delict=waarschuwing"><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i> Waarschuwing</a>
  <a href="reg.offence.php?delict=misdrijf"><i class="fas fa-mask"></i> Misdrijf</a>
  <a><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Arrestatiebevel</a>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
  <p>Database toevoeging</p>
  <a><i class="fas fa-car"></i> Voertuig</a>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
  <p>Meldkamer</p>
  <a href="meldkamer.php"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i> Meldkamer</a>
  </div>
  <p>
   &copy; www.lscdb.nl
  </p>
</nav_menu>

<nav_bar><div class="nav_bar_left"><i id="menubtn" onclick="closemen()" class="fas fa-bars"></i><img src="../img/lscdb_logo_white.png"></div><div class="logged_in"><?php echo $_SESSION['naam']; ?> | <?php echo $_SESSION['callsign']; ?></div><i class="fas fa-question"></i><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><i onclick="opensettings()" class="fas fa-cog"></i></nav_bar>
```

So to conclude, my headernav file i include using php works on some machines, while on others loads and dissapears directly after.

Comment: I assume `<!DOCTYPE html>` is already present in your index.php file. It might be the reason why it doesn't work with other machines (or browsers)

Comment: @fmsthird, no it is not cousing the problem couse i added it to try to fix the problem afterwards. but did not remove it when it diden't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution.... finally.

It turns out the header that has a position:fixed allways needs top:0; and left:0;, even if the header is allready in the correct position.